# Why does triangle law of vector addition seem to disobey triangle inequality?

Tags: vectors

I recently started learning about vectors,and one of the first things that was taught was Triangle law of vector addition. However I can't understand why triangle law of vector addition doesn't follow triangle inequality. [image]
For example, in the above diagram, shouldn't $R>A+B$ rather than being equal? Why is it not following triangle inequality?

Comment: The triangle inequality is about lengths.

Comment: Note that in your figure you have vectors $\vec R=\vec A+\vec B$. The lengths are then $R=|\vec R|\le|\vec A|+|\vec B|=A+B$.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the statement of the triangle law as well as that of the triangle inequality. Vector addition does follow the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Andrei even if the lengths are their mod, still the inequality should be strict right? If they become equal, there won't be a triangle but a straight line?

Comment: There is a $\leq$ in the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Randall well ok but in case of equality it won't be a traingle anymore. But I guess that would count as well

Comment: The "triangle" should not be taken 100% literally.  It's just a name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the sides of this triangle have lengths equal to the magnitudes of the vectors $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, and $\mathbf{R}$, respectively.

And, the triangle inequality says that the length of the side representing $\mathbf{R}$ in particular cannot exceed the sum of the lengths of the sides representing $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. That is,
$$
\lvert \mathbf{R} \rvert \leq \lvert \mathbf{A} \rvert + \lvert \mathbf{B} \rvert, 
$$
or in other words,
$$
\lvert \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} \rvert \leq \lvert \mathbf{A} \rvert + \lvert \mathbf{B} \rvert. 
$$

Answer (score 5):

The triangle inequality (i.e. sum of any two sides is always greater than the third one) holds true for lengths of sides in a triangle.

Therefore, in terms of lengths of vectors $|\vec A|, |\vec B|$ and $|\vec R|$ representing the sides of a triangle, the triangle inequality is satisfied as follows
$$|\vec R|<|\vec A|+|\vec B|$$
or $$R<A+B$$
Where, $R, A, $ and $B$ are the magnitudes of vectors $\vec R, \vec A$ and $\vec B$ respectively.

While the equality (triangle law) holds true for vector addition
$$\vec R=\vec A+\vec B$$